# Объект ItemsControl не соответствует своему источнику элементов

Tags: c#, wpf

Метод асинхронно парсит пользователей с сайта и заносит в список
`List<User> Users;`.

Этот список привязан к таблице `<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" />`

Если во время парсинга прокручивать таблицу с результатами возникает исключение:

> Объект ItemsControl не соответствует своему источнику элементов.

Почему это происходит?

---

Проблему решил этот ответ https://stackoverflow.com/a/12881558/6641468

Comment: попробуйте ObservableCollection вместо List

Comment: Имеет смысл оформить решение проблемы как ответ ;)

Comment: @FoggyFinder, Я не уверен, что это лучшее возможное решение, поэтому воздержусь)